# "Plátano" and "banana", geographical differences?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

I don't really speak Spanish, but I do know a few words and phrases here and there, and enjoy furthering what little knowledge I have. So, today I saw, in a Swedish newspaper, a reference to plantains (we call them "cooking bananas" over here), as being called *plátanos* in Spanish.

This seemed wrong to me, as from what little experience I have, *plátano* is the banana (the sweet kind), and *banana* refers to the plantain. That's what I found when visiting Spain a few years ago, and that is what my girlfriend, who learned Spanish from Chileans, told me.

So, am I right in guessing that this is all a big jumble, and that there is no right or wrong, in the global sense?

Comment: In Spain, the word "plátano" is used only to refer to "el plátano de Canarias", for any other origins the noun "banana" is used. In Hispanoamerica the use is different, as Envite explains in his answer.

Comment: en Cuba es muy dificil escuchar banana, se usa platano acompañado del tipo, por ejemplo platano fruta, platano macho, platano manzano, etc. en Colombia le dicen platano al que se usa para freir o cocinar, y al que se come como fruta le dicen banano o banana

Comment: @edivimo: Related anecdote: While traveling with my wife through the U.S. years ago, we stopped for lunch at a Mexican restaurant. Being from Costa Rica, we chatted up the waiter, who was a Mexican immigrant. Near the end of the meal, my wife, "suffering" from several weeks away from home, asked the waiter if he could convince the cook to prepare a *plátano frito* to satisfy a craving. He gave us the funniest look, then disappeared into the kitchen. A few minutes later, he emerged carrying a tray with a banana fried in oil. We all had a great laugh together after sorting out the confusion.

Comment: In Colombia, `plátano` is a plantain, the non-sweet kind, and `banana` the other. It's just different in different places I reckon.

Comment: In Argentina,  "banana" is the sweet fruit - "plátano" is a (unrelated) tree https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platanaceae (but we are aware that "platano" is our "banana" in other regions). Names of fruits and vegetables vary notoriously among Spanish-speaking countries https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyGFz-zIjHE

Comment: In Guatemala we call platano to the one you have to fry and banano to the one you eat raw.

Comment: Interesante lo que puso el de Colombia. Muy similar a Puerto Rico. Lo que en Colombia llaman patacones nosotros le llamamos tostones. Solo se hacen tostones con el plátano verde, tambien hacemos mofongo con el plátano verde; y similar al mofongo es el mangú, pero el mangú es de República Dominicana. Con el plátano maduro hacemos tajadas (sliced) muy ricas con huevo frito, pastelón con carne molida, pionono, etc. El guineo (banana) lo usamos tambien tanto verde como maduro. El maduro pues tiene muchísimos usos. El verde lo usamos para hacer pasteles (no tiene que ver con nada dulce, lo aclaro p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usage of the words "plátano" and "banana" depends slightly on the zones.

We can think that the most used usage is as follows:

"Plátano" is the name for a fruit coming from *Musa* genre plants, that can be eaten raw. Known as a source of potassium, uses to be sweet.

"Banana" is the name for a fruit coming also from *Musa* genre plants, that must be fried in order to be edible.

"Banano" and "Cambur" are regional synonyms for "Plátano".

E.g. Canary Islands banana (raw edible) is exported as "Plátano de Canarias".

**However, in some places the names are inverted! Which means Platano has to be fried and Banano can be eaten raw.** cf. http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musa_%C3%97_paradisiaca and the comment from @Joze below.

Comment: At least in Spain, plátanos and bananas are both raw edible, but plátanos are smaller but sweeter. Bananas are often considered as a cheaper alternative to plátanos.

Comment: @rafabayona That usage of 'bananas' in mainland spain comes from the name used in banana-exporting countries, and in order to separate them from Canary Islands 'plátanos'. But there is a different fruit, not usually seen in Spain, which is not raw edible.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. That kind of plátanos are called «plátanos macho»

Comment: In my experience, the usage in Spain is exactly as @rafabayona says in his comments.

Comment: @Gorpik Please specify which part of Spain. In Canary Islands we mostly use 'Plátano' for the raw edible fruit, either local or not, and 'Banano' (note the masculine) for the non raw edible one. 'Banana' (feminine) is a pejorative for plátanos imported from South America, which compete with local ones.

Comment: @Envite I did not know of this use in the Canary Islands, but I have never been there (should fix that), so I have not much experience on your usage. Anyway, your comment contradicts your answer. Answer: banana must be fried to eat; comment: banana is a South American plátano. Answer: banano is a regional synonym for plátano; comment: banano is not edible raw.

Comment: @Gorpik Please differentiate properly between the answer (as general and wide as possible) and the comment (local usage in a small territory).

Comment: Remember to add to your answer that it is inverted for the most part of central and south america. As the answer of edivimo says. `Plátano` has to be fried in order to be eaten and `Banano` can be eaten raw. This is true for *Panama, Costa Rica, Colombia, Venezuela, Ecuador, Peru, Honduras...* These are not small territories or populations.

Comment: Edited (I put bold and referred to your comment @Joze )

Comment: Could you add some details please. I read "However, in some places the names are inverted! Which means Platano has to be fried and Banano can be eaten raw.", but I don't see the previous occurrence of raw vs fried. Could you explain?

Answer (score 10):

[image]

Form left to right as we call them in Colombia:

1. *Plátano maduro*: Can be eaten raw but is usually cooked to make *tajadas*. The *tajadas* are usually cut long and after fried they look dark red/orange and are sweet.
2. *Plátano verde*: It is the same as the previous but not ripe. It has to be cooked/fried. It is usually cross cut, fried and then flattened to make *patacones* that are usually the fish side dish. This also can be made very big fro the whole *plátano* and used as a base for other things like *guacamole* and all kinds of stuff and they are called *patacones con... (todo)*
3. *Banano*: This is one of the main exports of the country. It is always used when ripe and is eaten raw. Good source of potassium.
4. *Guineo*: It is used ripe but mostly green. It has to be cooked but is mainly used on boiled meals like soups or beans. It is used diced.
5. *Plátano colicero*: same as the *Guineo*
6. _Murrapo or "banano bocadillo": It is a very small (10 cm) kind of banana. It is very sweet and it is eaten raw.

The cooked foods mention above look like these:

Patacones de plátano verde:
[image: Patacones]  [image]
Tajadas de plátano maduro:
[image]

Comment: Great explanation. I loved the images.

Comment: @DGaleano an Bogotá la número 6 le decimos "banano bocadillo", en qué parte de Colombia le dicen "Murrapo"?, Excelente las imagenes, aclaran mucho

Comment: @alvalongo Murrapo le decimos los paisas. Gracias por el aporte. No se quien rechazó tu edición. Lo incluyo.

Comment: @DGaleano no me había enterado del rechazo; a la descripción del "Plátano maduro" sería bueno aclarar que la consistencia es suave y que entre más negra la cáscara es más suave y mejor para hacer "tajadas" (tal vez se podría traducir como "slices"?)

Answer (score 9):

Agronomist here from Costa Rica. We call **plátano** to the fruit that you need to cook. The cooking is necessary because this fruit had starch, but when is mature some of that starch turns to sugar, so is still sweet, but *starchy*, so you still can eat it raw. We call **banano** the fruit you always eat raw, because all the starch is converted in sugar when matures. If you cook a **banano** in hot water or fried you make a caramel mess.

Ecuador, Costa Rica and Colombia are the 3 world main exporters of the sweet raw fruit, and in the three countries is called **banano**. Most of the production of **plátano** is for the local market and rarely is exported.

Also, the french called *banano*: **banane dessert** and to *plátano*: **banane plantain**, called only **plantain** in french speaking African countries (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banane_plantain).
In portuguese, the sweet is **banana**, and the starchy is **banana-pão** or **banana-da-terra** (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana).

So, the correct designation is *banano* the sweet, and *plátano* the starchy in the tropical hispanic countries. México, España, Chile and other non-tropical hispanic countries only use the word **plátano** for the *banano* because usually they don't know the starchy variety, that isn't exported.

Answer (score 2):

In Panama, "guineo" is used for the fruit you eat raw and "plátano" for the one you have to cook. Interestingly, the fruit you need to cook is broken into two categories depending on whether it's ripe or not. The green plantain is sliced cross-wise, the pieces are fried, then removed and flattened and fried again. Those are called "patacones" ("tostones" in Puerto Rico).Ripe plantains are sliced length-wise and fried. Those are called "tajadas." You don't cut green ones length-wise and you don't cut ripe ones cross-wise.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "cambur" is used in Venezuela for the sweat banana which you can eat raw. "Plátano" is in Venezuela for frying and cooking, but in some other countries (México and some Central American countries) the expression "Plátano macho" is for the one you cannot eat raw and simply the word "Plátano" is for the one which is sweat and you eat it raw.

In El Salvador they call the sweat banana "guineo" and plátano is the one for cooking or frying.

Comment: I disagree with the part about the Central American countries, here *banano* is the raw-sweet fruit. You can verify that with google searches of "Honduras banano" or "Guatemala banano" and in the news and in exporter companies use the word *banano* and in a few caribeans countries use *guineo*. The weirdest is from the venezuelans with *cambur*.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Costa Rica, and there we call it 4 things:

- Plátano -  does not taste good raw, must be cooked
- Banano - Long thinner - Fruity eat it raw
- Banana - little FAT ones - fruity eat them raw

All of them fall into the guineos category, thus we can call them *guineos* as well, and ALL of them can be fried.